# Trouble with WPBakery, putting one image above the other

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have WPBakery installed on my wordpress website, and I have tried to have two images in a single widget in a row divided into 5 columns, the two images being in a single column.

One of the images however is a sort of a custom stylized picture frame for the other image. I managed to partially solve the issue by applying a margin of "-140%" on the top margin. Unfortunately I can't get the image to stretch out to fit the frame, also when changing the viewport to be smaller (mobile sized for example), the frame scales proportionally as it should, while the image it self shrinks.

Can anyone help me out on making the image scale proportionally with the image, and also making sure it stretches to the size of the frame?

Note: The images might not be the same resolution as the frame, but i need the image to be stretched to those dimensions.

[Here is how it looks on a 1080p monitor, notice how its not stretched to the frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmG6c.png)

[When it is shrunk to a mobile viewport](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZ6L1.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my professional opinion of over 13 years of web development in a business setting, my answer to you is use ONE image.  Have a .PSD project for these.  Have your image frame as one layer, and use your normal images in another layer on top.  When you want to create one of these images, open up the .PSD project, highlight the image to be replaced, and import the new.  You may have to crop the new to be the dimensions of the last one and play with the centering x and y.  Then, save your new image at full size.  It will scale down because it is ONE image, not one image with a hacktastic image background.

Comment: This was my alternative if I couldn't figure out how to write the code to handle the scaling of the two images, guess I should listen to the professionals if they say so!